# netbeans replace text with regex

Tags: php, regex, netbeans

I need to upgrade my software from php 5.2.6 to 7.00

I have to update some outdated code like building arrays.

Array keys must be declared in double quotes.

I want to use netbeans to search and replace occurrences using RegExr.

Substitution does not have to be performed if the key is named with a variable or contains a number.

I was able to find a nearly working regex expression.

The problem is that the first replaced letter is removed.

I ask for your help and enclose the result I would like.

Thank you

PROBLEM
From

```
$array = array();
$array[penne] = 1;   <- my actual code (deprecated)
$array[$name] = 2;
$array[0] = 3;
$array["gomme"] = 4;
```

To

```
$array = array();
$array["penne"] = 1;   <- correction I want
$array[$name] = 2;
$array[0] = 3;
$array["gomme"] = 4;
```

REPLACE WITH NETBEANS REGEXR

[image]
RESULT

```
$array = array();
$array["enne"] = 1;   <- NO!!!    WHY ????
$array[$name] = 2;
$array[0] = 3;
$array["gomme"] = 4;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
\[([^\"$0-9][^][]*)]
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/0s81mP/4).

*Details*:

- `\[` - a `[` char
- `([^"$0-9][^][]*)` - Group 1 (`\1`): any char other than a `"`, `$` and a digit and then any zero or more chars other than `[` and `]` chars
- `\]` - a `]` char.